# IOS drawing the arrow lines between 2 GMSMarkers onto GoogleMap

Tags: ios, google-maps, core-graphics, google-maps-sdk-ios, polyline

I would like to implement the class with GMSPolyline can draw arrows instead of straight-lines to show the path with direction from one google map marker into another. Is it possible for the Objective C to inherit two classes using composition as below ? 
The below is my workout:

```
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ClassA : GMSPolyline {
}

-(void)methodA;

@end

@interface ClassB : UIView {
}

-(void)methodB;

@end

@interface MyPolyline : NSObject {
    ClassA *a;
    ClassB *b;
}

-(void)methodA;
-(void)methodB;

@end




- (void)addMarkers
{
    if([array count] > 0){

        [mapView_ clear];
        GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
        GMSMutablePath *currentPath = [GMSMutablePath path];

        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {

            CheckPoints *cp = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cp.getLatitude , cp.getLongitude);
            GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
            //  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
            marker.position = position;
            NSLog( @"%d", cp.getState );
            NSLog( @"%f", cp.getLatitude);
            NSLog( @"%f", cp.getLongitude );
            NSLog( @"%@", cp.getDesp );
            marker.title = cp.getDesp;

            NSString *tmpLat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", position.latitude];
            NSString *tmpLong = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", position.longitude];
            marker.snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", tmpLat,tmpLong];
            UIColor *color;
            GMSPolyline *polyline ;
            if (cp.getState ==0) {
                color = [UIColor greenColor];
                [path addLatitude:cp.getLatitude longitude:cp.getLongitude];
            } else {
                color = [UIColor redColor];
            }
            if(i > [array indexOfObject:array.lastObject] -2){
                [currentPath addLatitude:cp.getLatitude longitude:cp.getLongitude];
            }
            polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
            polyline.geodesic = YES;
            polyline.strokeWidth = 5.f;
         // polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
            GMSStrokeStyle *solidRed = [GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            GMSStrokeStyle *solidRGreen = [GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            polyline.spans = @[[GMSStyleSpan spanWithStyle:solidRed segments:[array count]-1],
                               [GMSStyleSpan spanWithStyle:solidRGreen segments:2]];
            marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:color];
            marker.map = mapView_;
            polyline.map = mapView_;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but here's one option: add a GMSMarker with a custom arrowhead icon to the appropriate path endpoints, set its rotation according to the slope of the given line segment (arctan dy/dx), and make sure it's set as flat rather than billboard (so it rotates naturally as the user rotates the view). Here's a screenshot:

[image: directed GMSPolyline]

Comment: Can you give code exampple for this screenshot, please?